# How to create a Proxy over Apache to Google Cloud and handle 403 failover?

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, proxypass

**Summary:**

I'm trying to proxy images over Apache to Google Cloud.

In case of image does not exist, I want to forward a request to a different route which will return the image and save it on Google Cloud for the next time.

**Legends:**

Local media domain used for proxy: **media.homestead**

The site where the request should be forwarded(no redirect) if the image does not exist: **mainsite.homestead**

Google cloud bucket: **storage.googleapis.com/mymedia.appspot.com**

**Case 1:**

http://media.homestead/dimension/150x100/sport.jpg

The image exists on google cloud, so the user will get an image response.

**Case 2:**

http://media.homestead/dimension/600x400/sport.jpg

The image does not exist, and the user should get a response from mainsite.homestead/dimension/150x100/sport.jpg

Why?

Because there is ErrorDocument 403 to cover that case.
We get header status 403 from Google Cloud if the image does not exist.

**Configuration which I'm using for Apache:**

```
LoadModule headers_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule ssl_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName media.homestead
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerAlias media.homestead

    Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
    Header always append X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
    Header always append X-Content-Type-Options nosniff

    Header unset X-GUploader-UploadID
    Header unset alt-svc
    Header unset alternate-protocol
    Header unset x-goog-hash
    Header unset x-goog-generation
    Header unset x-goog-metageneration
    Header unset x-goog-stored-content-encoding
    Header unset x-goog-stored-content-length
    Header unset x-goog-storage-class
    Header unset Set-Cookie

    RequestHeader set X-SCHEME https
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https
    RequestHeader set Host "https://storage.googleapis.com/mymedia.appspot.com"

    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLProxyVerify none
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off

    ProxyErrorOverride On

    <Location />
        ProxyPass http://storage.googleapis.com/mymedia.appspot.com/
        ProxyPassReverse http://storage.googleapis.com/mymedia.appspot.com/
    </Location>


    <Location /media>
        ProxyPass http://mainsite.homestead/dimension
        ProxyPassReverse http://mainsite.homestead/dimension
    </Location>

    ErrorDocument 403 /media
    ErrorDocument 404 /media
</VirtualHost>
```

**Content of PHP script on mainsite.homestead:**

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];exit;
```

**Problem:**

Problem is that when I print the current URL on mainsite, I get "/dimension" instead of "/dimension/600x400/sport.jpg"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was finally solved.

I have replaced these lines:

```
    <Location /media>
        ProxyPass http://mainsite.homestead/dimension
        ProxyPassReverse http://mainsite.homestead/dimension
    </Location>

    ErrorDocument 403 /media
    ErrorDocument 404 /media
```

With the following two:

```
    <Location /media>
        ProxyPass http://mainsite.homestead
        ProxyPassReverse http://mainsite.homestead
    </Location>
    ErrorDocument 403 /media/%{REQUEST_URI}
    ErrorDocument 404 /media/%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Now I'm getting the requested URL "/dimension/600x400/sport.jpg".